# Submitting a Rails form leads to a Does not Exist Page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am not quite understanding why hitting the submit button on my simple Rails form refreshes the page to a "The page you were looking for doesn't exist" when the URL does not even change. Submitting the form with valid data also does not seem to create such an entry into any database. Any direction would be appreciated.

**Below is the /app/views/helps/new.html.erb**

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden; 
} 
.container {
   margin-top: 60px;
} 

</style>

<% if logged_in? %>
  <div class= "container">
    <% provide(:title, "Submit Inquiry") %>
    <br><h2><center>Submit Inquiry</center></h2>
    <p></p>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <%= form_for(:helps, url: new_help_path) do |f| %>

          <%= f.label :email %>
          <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
          <%= f.label :text %>
          <%= f.text_area :text, class: 'form-control' %>
          <p></p>
          <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% else %>
  <div class="alert alert-danger"><br>
    <br><%= link_to "Please log in to continue", root_path %>
  </div>
<%end%>
```

**Below is the helps_controller**

```
class HelpsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :get_user,         only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :valid_user,       only: [:edit, :update]

  def new
  end

  def create
      @user= User.find(params[:id])
      if current_user?(@user)
        flash[:success] = "Inquiry submitted."
        redirect_to new_help_path
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = "Only users can submit inquiries."
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end


  private

    def get_user
      @user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
    end

    # Confirms a valid user.
    def valid_user
      unless (@user && @user.activated? &&
              @user.authenticated?(:reset, params[:id]))
        redirect_to root_url
      end
    end

end
```

**Below is my routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'sessions#new'
  get '/home', to: 'static_pages#home'
  get '/add/parts', to: 'static_pages#part'
  get '/add/projects', to: 'static_pages#project'
  get '/add/vendors', to: 'static_pages#vendor'
  get '/signup', to: 'users#new'
  post '/signup', to: 'users#create'
  get '/login', to: 'sessions#new'
  post '/login', to: 'sessions#create'


  delete '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'

  resources :users
  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  #users can generate new passwords (reset), and change them 
  resources :password_resets, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
  resources :helps,  only: [:new, :create]
end
```

**Below is the relevant code from my _header.html.erb**

```
<body>
  <header>
    <ul class= "nav">
      <li><a class="active" href="/home">Home</a></li>
      <% if logged_in? %>
        <li><%= link_to "Profile", edit_user_path(current_user.id) %></li>
      <%end%>
      <li id= "options">
        <a href="#">Add</a>
        <ul class= "subnav">
            <li><%= link_to "Part", add_parts_path%></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Project", add_projects_path%></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Vendor", add_vendors_path%></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><%= link_to "Help", new_help_path, method: :create %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Log Out", logout_path, method: :delete %></li>
      <li id= "search">
        <form action= "" method= "get">
            <input type="text" name="search_text" id= "search_text" placeholder="Search Page"/>
            <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
        </form>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </header>
  </body>
```

**Below is my index.html.erb**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Posts</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Body</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @posts.each do |post| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= post.title %></td>
        <td><%= post.body %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', post %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
    <% @helps.each do |help| %>
      <%= help.email %>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Post', new_post_path %>
```

Comment: Please share the controller

Comment: Added the controller, thanks

Comment: Thank you. Please run rake routes and see whether new_help_path exists. You can also check config/routes.rb

Comment: Yes it exists. I can also access the form in my browser; the issue is that submitting breaks the link

Comment: Oh. Nothing gets created in the form. You're only finding the user, but not calling a .create or .new and .save

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are finding a user in the create method, and then redirecting to new_helps_path.
    def new 
     @help = Help.new
    end
    def create
          @user= User.find(params[:id])
         # @help(or whatever the model is named) = Help.new
          if current_user?(@user)
            @help.create(email: params[:email])
            flash[:success] = "Inquiry submitted."
            redirect_to new_help_path
        else
          flash.now[:danger] = "Only users can submit inquiries."
          redirect_to root_url
        end
      end

In `<%= form_for(@help, url: RAKE ROUTES AND PICK THE PATH WITH ACTION CREATE) do |f| %>`, the path should be where you are posting the form, in this case, it's the create method with a POST

resources :helps,  only: [:create, index, show, new]

```
def index
@helps = Help.all
end
```

then in index.html.erb

```
<% @helps.each do |help| %>
  <%= help.email %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hmm so if new_help_path is the url to the form, from which entries should be stored into a database, would placing `@help = Help.new` before the redirect still store the data properly? I also just added my routes.rb

Comment: So `@help` is what would be referenced in the form. The model for which your building the form. Once `@help.create`is called and the form stored in the db, you will be redirected to new_help_path, which I assume is a path to create a new form? Could you please try redirecting to a different path, perhaps root?

You could redirect to index for example, where you could view all of the forms that were created (provided that you have an index method where you sent @helps = Help.all , and in your view, you can loop over @helps

Comment: I implemented the changes and tried redirecting to root. Unfortunately, the results did not change- The page kills itself and does not redirect. The `flash[:success]` portion also does not occur

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to changed the form_for bit. Please try again, and check the output in the console. 
Can you for now remove the current_user(@user) logic

Comment: In the form, I changed the line to `<%= form_for @help do |f| %>` and the form no longer shows up

Comment: It might just be a different view. What does the console show when you go to the page that's supposed to have the form? Is the user logged in? Try to remove that conditional for now. Also, make sure you restart your server.

Comment: I am getting two errors: `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/help"):` and `AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'index' could not be found for HelpsController):`

Comment: Great! So you need to add   resources :helps,  only: [:new, :create, index, show] (and eventually the matching views). Run `heroku run rake routes` and use the path to a new form to access the form

Comment: Also, make sure to add the index method in the controller

Comment: Well that is actually the problem. I had already added `:index` into the `resources :helps`. And the path to a new form is */helps/new* which is actually what I am trying to link to but the page apparently "doesn't exist"

Comment: might be a dumb question, but how do I format the index in the controller?

Comment: No dumb question. I added the index controller in my answer

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't realize you replied yesterday. I updated my code but now I am getting a routing issue- "/helps/new" does not exist. Let me update my question with my `index.html.erb` and a header `_header.html.erb` that links to the form.

Comment: To confirm, is root still redirecting to new_helps_path? So now the error from heroku logs is /new doesn’t exist ? Please paste the exact error. I’m seeing that you’ve already set a def new method in you helps_controller. Try`def new @help = Help.new` end

Comment: I actually  took out the part of the code that redirected to root. I figured since the execution never seems to hit the `if` statement, it wouldn't redirect anyways. The error that I am getting is: `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/helps/new"):
`

Comment: Did you add `def new @help = Help.new end ` ?

Comment: Yes, I added that to the helps_controller

Comment: I made a mistake in the initial code I shared with you from the create method. Instead of `@help = Help.new` and then `@help.save`, I gave you Help.new then @help.create. I've updated it. Try that please

Comment: Made the change. Two errors: `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/helps/new")` and `ActionController::UnknownFormat (HelpsController#index is missing a template for this request format and variant. request.formats: ["text/html"] request.variant: [] `

Comment: Also getting the warning: `NOTE! For XHR/Ajax or API requests, this action would normally respond with 204 No Content: an empty white screen. Since you're loading it in a web browser, we assume that you expected to actually render a template, not nothing, so we're showing an error to be extra-clear. If you expect 204 No Content, carry on. That's what you'll get from an XHR or API request. Give it a shot.):
`

Comment: Yeah, you're doing a post request instead of get.  Let me know whether you want to do a screenshare to fix this quickly

Comment: Sure that would be great. Let me know when you are online

Comment: I'm available today. Let's try 2pm PDT

Comment: How about sometime in the afternoon today? PDT

Comment: sorry dude. email me at ahbabousara@gmail